# How can I debug a SQLite Extension with XCode 4

Tags: sqlite, xcode4

I am developing a [virtual table](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) implementation for SQLite as a [loadable extension](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions) in C using XCode 4. I can fire up the SQLite shell and load my extension, but I have no idea how to use the debugger in XCode to debug the process.

If this is impossible, does anyone have tips for debugging my code?

Comment: Isn't `gdb -p <sqlitepid>` good enough?

Comment: I ended up creating a project for the SQLite shell and referencing the extension from there. I would fire up the shell and was able to step into the debugger when using the extension in SQL.